# Strange Assembly Language Addition

Tags: assembly, binary, hex, addition, cpu-registers

I have been studying Assembly Language lately and I came across an add statement that I don't understand.

```
ebx=00000003;
esi=0FFFFFFFFh;
add ebx,esi
The Result was: ebx=00000002
```

How is this possible?
Can someone explain me how the addition took place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a subtraction masked as an addition.
The instruction `add ebx,esi` added the value `-1` in ESI to the value of `3` in EBX which results in the value `2`.

This is possible because of the [two complement binary addition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

```
ebx=000000003h;   3
esi=0FFFFFFFFh;  -1
--------------;   +
ebx=000000002h;   2
```

The subtraction is achieved by an overflow from 0FFFFFFFFh(`-1`) to 00000000h(`0`).

Comment: 2s complement basically means flipping 0 to 1 and vice versa, and adding +1 to the result...
How is 0FFFFFFFFh = -1?

Comment: If it is a *signed* number it is `-1`. If it is and *unsigned* number, the values is `UINT_MAX`. (and yes, you have the two's compliment calculation correct)

Comment: @Ramesh: Flipping all 0s to 1s and vice versa is called ones-complement (the x86 [`NOT` instruction](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/NOT.html)). Flipping all 0s to 1s and vice versa and adding one is called two-complement as in the link(the x86 [`NEG` instruction](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/NEG.html)).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin You have a great knowledge. How come you know about everything?

Comment: The older you get, the more stay facts you collect in you brain... I've been around for a long time...

Comment: You can even treat it as two unsigned values, then simply doing addition from lowest bits... `3` is `0011`, `F` is `1111` => first bits from right are both 1 -> 0 + carry, second bits are both 1 and carry to it -> 1 + carry, third bits are 1+0+carry -> 0 + carry -> and this will repeat till last 32th bit, leaving you with carry. I.e. result is `00....0010` binary = `2`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Sir, can you please explain the working calculations? I understand about 2's Complement and signed/unsigned numbers. Can you please help me understand why 0FFFFFFFFh=-1?

Comment: it's not -1. It only acts like a -1 if you add it. note an example in decimal, with 4 digit numbers: take 2345 and add 9999. the result will be 2344 and an overflow. you're not "seeing" the 1 in front (because you only have 4 digits), and the result is the same like you'd be subtracting 0001

Comment: Thanks a lot to everyone who has helped to give a result for my query. I would no knowledge about certain things without stack overflowers.